# Check that $u_4\bar{u_3}u_2\bar{u_1}=i$ and $\bar{u_1}u_2\bar{u_3}u_4=1$ so the product of the four reflections is indeed $q \to iq$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, quaternions

This is an exercise from "Naive Lie Theory" and $u_1, u_2, ...,u_4$ are the unit quaternions. I have read the section many times but still don't understand. Can someone explain the material and solve the exercise?

Comment: Are $u_1=1$,$u_2=i$,$u_3=j$,$u_4=k$ ? Or they are generic unitary quaternions?

Comment: @EmilioNovati they are as you first suggested.

Comment: If they are so there is something wrong. I suggest that you test if there is some typo and specify what are the $u_i$ in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're struggling about problem 2.5 in Naive Lie Theory.

In the problem 2.5.2 and 2.5.3, we get four unit quaternions u1,u2,u3,u4. The composition of two rotation maps which was introduced in problem 2.5.2 and 2.5.3 is the map which you want.